# Unsat core in Minisat

Tags: constraint-programming, sat, sat-solvers

Is there any API call in minisat to extract unsat core or any other method for the same.

I want to extract the unsat core for every invocation of the solver and then work on the unsat core.

Comment: Look into minisats `analyzeFinal`. But before putting lots of work into it (understanding it incl. the necessary assumptions), i would recommend looking into [pysat](https://pysathq.github.io/usage.html) first during prototyping. Either as alternative wrapper or for analyzing how they use `analyzeFinal` (might be obfuscated due to patch-heavy install)

Comment: Unfortunately I am allowed to use only minisat. But what I've done so far is I have labelled each clause with an extra variable say !lbl(negative polarity) and while solving and in assumptions I am assuming lbl (positive) polarity.. so minisat has this vector called conflict.. which has all the lbl of the clauses that are in unsat core!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

MiniSat is quite an old program at this point.  At the very least, you should look into one of the solvers entered into a [recent SAT competition](http://sat2018.forsyte.tuwien.ac.at/index.php?cat=results), e.g. [Glucose](https://www.labri.fr/perso/lsimon/glucose/).  The competitions have required SAT solvers to emit [DRAT proofs](https://arxiv.org/pdf/1610.06229.pdf) of unsatisfiability since 2013.  Run whichever solver you choose and have it dump its DRAT proof into proof.out.  Feed proof.out into the [drat-trim](https://github.com/marijnheule/drat-trim) utility with the -c option, which will produce an UNSAT core in DIMACS format.  I.e.

```
drat-trim originalproblem.cnf proof.out -c core.cnf
```

Note that you don't have to use a MiniSat clone; any modern solver that emits DRAT proofs can have its proof fed into drat-trim to yield an UNSAT core.

Comment: Will surely look into this..Unfortunately I am allowed to use only minisat. But what I've done so far is I have labelled each clause with an extra variable say !lbl(negative polarity) and while solving in assumptions I am assuming lbl (positive) polarity.. so minisat has this vector called conflict.. which has all the lbl of the clauses that are in unsat core!